# How to remove clock symbol in UTCDatetime Field on form(Dynamics ax)?

Tags: axapta, datetime-format, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have a UTC date time field on form.

But i need only date to be displayed so i kept display as date.

But i am getting a clock symbol in the field.

Is there any way i can remove that symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue. I changed the Property of "TimeZoneIndicator " property to "Never" on form field level. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the calender symbol in the DateTime edit control.

You can disable the hour, minutes and seconds display on the extended data type (`TimeHours` attribute etc.) or on the DateTime form control, and AX removes the space for the time. However AX still shows the calendar icon, even if you set the `LookupButton` attribute to `Never`, unless you also set `AllowEdit` to `No`.

What you can do is replace the DateTime control with an edit or display method control, and do the required conversions yourself.

```
edit date transDate(boolean _set, date _date)
{
    TimeOfDay time;
    if (_set)
    {
        time = DateTimeUtil::time(DateTimeUtil::applyTimeZoneOffset(utc, DateTimeUtil::getUserPreferredTimeZone()));
        utc  = DateTimeUtil::removeTimeZoneOffset(DateTimeUtil::newDateTime(_date, time), DateTimeUtil::getUserPreferredTimeZone());
    }
    return DateTimeUtil::date(DateTimeUtil::applyTimeZoneOffset(utc, DateTimeUtil::getUserPreferredTimeZone()));
}
```

The `utc` variable holds the saved date/time value.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. The clock symbol i am saying is not calendar icon. I am getting Circular clock symbol. I observed that when i kept "TimeZonePreference Property of EDT to NoConversion" then i am getting clock symbol. If i kept it as User/Auto then my functionality is breaking. But i have to get rid of that clock. Thats what i am worried. Any idea of getting rid of clock symbol without changing TimeZonePreference property from NoConversion to Other values.?

Comment: Its AX2012 R3 version.

Comment: There is no clock symbol in prior versions, I have not tried the R3 version yet. You could try to apply the work-around in the answer.

Comment: Oh ok. Sure i will try to do some workaround and will update you. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Not yet. I didnt get time to check that. Will update once i go through that.